# Calling Web Services with PHP SoapClient - How to?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am going crazy starting off with Web Services. I am trying to call the following WSDL using PHP and keep getting nowhere:

http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/usg/SessionCreateRQ.wsdl

I found the following piece of code on the net, from someone with similar problems, but I could not get it to work either:

`$soap = new SoapClient('http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/usg/SessionCreateRQ.wsdl', 
                        array( 
                            'trace' => true, 
                            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 
                            "exceptions" => 0));`

$eb = new EbXmlMessage(); 
$sec = new Security(); 
$scrq = new SessionCreateRQ();

try { 
    $omg = $soap->SessionCreateRQ($scrq, $sec,$eb); 
    } 
catch (Exception $e)
 
{ 
    print_r($e); 
} 
//debug 
    print "Request: \n". 
          htmlspecialchars($soap->__getLastRequestHeaders()) ."\n"; 
    print "Request: \n". 
           htmlspecialchars($soap->__getLastRequest()) ."\n"; 
    print "Response: \n". 
           $soap->__getLastResponseHeaders()."\n"; 
    print "Response: \n". 
           $soap->__getLastResponse()."\n"; 

print_r($omg); 
//the first envelope headers 
class EbXmlMessage 
{ 
    public $From = array('PartyId' => 'mysite.com'); 
    public $To = array('PartyId' => 'myprovider.com');
 
    public $CPAId = 'ZZZZ'; 
    public $ConversationId = 'myconv@id.com'; 
    public $Service = 'Session';// or SessionCreate?
    public $Action = 'SessionCreateRQ'; 
    public $MessageData = array(
        'MessageId' => 'messageid', 
        'Timestamp' => '2009-04-18T15:15:00Z');
     
} 
//the security token 
class Security { 
    public $Username = "xxxxx"; 
    public $Password = "yyyyy"; 
    public $Organization = "ZZZZ"; 
    public $Domain = "DEFAULT"; 
} 
//this is suppoused to be the payload, or the xml i need to send at the end 
class SessionCreateRQ 
{ 
    public $POS = array( 
            'Source' => array( 
                '_'=>"", 
                'PseudoCityCode'=>'ZZZZ' 
            )); 
} 



I keep getting the following error:

Response: 
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 19 Apr 2009 22:21:34 GMT
Connection: close
Server: SWS

Response:

> soap-env:Client.InvalidEbXmlMessageUnable to internalize
>   messagejavax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to internalize message    at
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.(MessageImpl.java:135)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:32)
>     at
>   com.sabre.universalservices.gateway.control.SoapProcessor.getRequest(SoapProcessor.java:263)
>     at
>   com.sabre.universalservices.gateway.control.WSGateway.handleRequest(WSGateway.java:380)
>     at
>   com.sabre.universalservices.gateway.control.WSGateway.doPost(WSGateway.java:306)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:852)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:584)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1508)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595) Caused by:
>   javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Invalid
>   Content-Type:application/soap+xml     at
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.verify(MessageImpl.java:159)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.(MessageImpl.java:91)
>     ... 19 more
>
> SoapFault Object (
>       [message:protected] => Unable to internalize message
>       [string:private] =>  .....

This service should be validating me on the system and returning a security object to be used in later calls - a string(?) which I can then store in a session variable for the following calls.

Any help GREATLY appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that there is a **faultcode** value in the SoapFault Object:

```
[faultcode] => soap-env:Client.InvalidEbXmlMessage
```

So that may be a useful avenue to start debugging.

I tried comparing the structure of your EbXmlMessage to the [XSD](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/ebxml-msg/schema/msg-header-2_0.xsd) and the [schema documentation](http://www.buldocs.com/xnsdoc/samples/docs/oasis/ebxml/message-2.0/msg-header-2_0.xsd/index.html), but I couldn't see any obvious reason that it was declared invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the Content-type header to text/xml?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **wsdl2php**. It makes php classes out of the wsdl file. It uses php's SoapClient to send the data.

Here is a nice post explaining how to do it:

http://itworkarounds.blogspot.com/2011/10/simple-soap-client-with-wsdl2php-using.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use nuSOAP. I don't like PHP native SoapClient. nuSoap generates for you a wsdl so you don't have to worry about how to make one.. Here's [nuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) and here's a simple example code or you can download whole working code [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!eEdiTDIA!WUezp088c13IMA5TKnWh63E89jBGyaKRiqYLvBL5b3g) :

**Server** :

```
<?php
// include the SOAP classes
require_once('nuSOAP/lib/nusoap.php');

function HelloWorld(){
return 'HelloWorld'; // Returns HelloWorld string
}

function Hello($name){
return 'Hello '.$name; // Returns Hello with name string parameter
}



// create the server object
$server = new nusoap_server();

// Initialize WSDL support
$server->configureWSDL('webservicenamespace', 'urn:webservicenamespace');



$server->register('HelloWorld',             array(), array('result' => 'xsd:string')); //xsd:string; xsd:boolean; xsd:integer and so on..
$server->register('Hello',                  array('name' => 'xsd:string'), array('result' => 'xsd:string')); // array('parametername' => 'parametertype'),array('result' => 'returntype');


if (isset($error))
{
    $fault =
            $server->fault('soap:Server','',$error);
}

// send the result as a SOAP response over HTTP $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
$server->service($post);
?>
```

**Client** :

```
<?php
// Pull in the NuSOAP code
require_once('nuSOAP/lib/nusoap.php');

// Create the client instance

$client = new nusoap_client('http://pathtourl/sample_webservice.php?wsdl', true);

// Check for an error
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
    // Display the error
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    // At this point, you know the call that follows will fail
}

// Call the SOAP method
$result = $client->call('Hello', array('name' => 'Scott')); // Call function name, parameters;

// Check for a fault
if ($client->fault) {
    echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
} else {
    // Check for errors
    $err = $client->getError();
    if ($err) {
        // Display the error
        echo '<h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    } else {
        // Display the result
        echo '<h2>Result</h2><pre>';
        print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
    }
}
// Display the request and response
echo '<h2>Request</h2>';
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
echo '<h2>Response</h2>';
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
// Display the debug messages
echo '<h2>Debug</h2>';
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->debug_str, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Now when you want to make a client you need your wsdl you can simply get it by adding *?wsdl* on your link i.e( *webservice.php?wsdl* )

Hope this helps :) Good luck with your web service.